# Polyfill for PerformanceObserver API to Implement Server Traffic Measurement

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, webapi

I'm currently utilizing the **PerformanceObserver** API to measure **server traffic** for given endpoints on the client side. However, I'm exploring alternative solutions due to potential limitations or lack of support in certain environments.
Here's the code snippet for reference:

```
const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
  list.getEntries().forEach((entry) => {
    const request = entry.responseEnd - entry.requestStart;
    console.log('Request time:', request);
  });
});

observer.observe({ type: "resource", buffered: true });

// Simulating a fetch request
const endpoint = 'https://example.com/api/data';

fetch(endpoint, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors'
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log('Data received:', data))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

In my actual application, there might be several endpoints(servers) to measure the traffic of and it's crucial to account for the time a request spends in the task queue.
Are there alternative solutions or approaches that can effectively handle this requirement?